# How can I register a client-side event listener on a server-side event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

(Assuming it's even possible in .Net, of course.)

Ultimately, what I want to accomplish is an AJAX-based messaging system.
I already have a database table for messages, and an ASPX to add new messages (and declare old messages no longer relevant).

The current messaging system simply polls the server every 15 seconds, and re-pulls the current message set.

What I am looking to do is:
On $(document).ready(), register an ajax callback function that listens for a server-side event (e.g., MessagesUpdated)
On table insert/update, fire MessagesUpdated server-side.

This way, whenever the table is updated (or new records added), any clients listening know that new data is available and can re-poll the server then.

Ideally, I'd also like to make the new data available as an event argument (to minimize re-polling the db).

I can find references to something like this in other languages, but I cannot find any actual code examples to get me started.

Assuming this is possible to do via .Net, can anyone help get me started on this?

I'm using the 2.0 Framework.
Also while I added a VB.Net tag, I can read C# reasonably well, so please feel free to post in either language.

Thanks in advance!

Pete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look into long polling. Basically what it does is set a long timeout period on AJAX requests. The client then waits for the server to respond. This is much more efficient and instantaneous than sending requests every few seconds.

[How to do a long polling client in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530572/how-to-do-a-long-polling-client-in-c)

Comment: Thank you all for the advice! After extensive research, and given my available server, I believe that Long Polling is the way to go (server won't support WebSockets, and SignalR downgrades to Long Polling when the server won't support WebSockets anyway).

Comment: Facebook (even twitter, hotmail also) works by polling the server after every few seconds. It is much easier that way. You can use fiddler to check by yourself. They don't have to worry about subscribers and publishers. They got more than half a million servers so scale is not a problem. They could have done subscriber\publisher model but they did not.

Answer (score 1):

For modern browsers, you could use [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebSockets) to open a continuous connection to the server, through which the server could notify you of a server-side event.  In browsers without websockets support, you would need to use long polling as mentioned in mrtsherman's answer.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 introduced websockets to address this issue, but support is sparse. If you used it you would need a fallback, which would probably be the long polling mrtsherman described.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it will work with .NET 2.0, but if you can work around that, you should check out [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR).  SignalR is a complete client- and server-side solution with JS on client and ASP.NET on the back end to create these kinds of applications.  There's a good summary [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx).

Quoting directly from that blog post:

*On the client*

```
$(function () {
// Proxy created on the fly
var chat = $.connection.chat;

// Declare a function on the chat hub so the server can invoke it
chat.addMessage = function (message) {
    $('#messages').append('<li>' + message + '</li>');
};

$("#broadcast").click(function () {
    // Call the chat method on the server
    chat.send($('#msg').val());
});

// Start the connection
$.connection.hub.start();
});
```

*And on the server*

```
public class Chat : Hub
{
    public void Send(string message)
    {
        // Call the addMessage method on all clients
        Clients.addMessage(message);
    }
}
```