# Standing HTTP connection

Tags: c#, http, atmosphere

**What I'm trying to do**

I'm trying to open a connection to this streaming webservice that uses the atmosphere framework. I need to be able to open a connection and wait for the service to send down an event but I really have no idea how to do this.

The most important thing is to keep the connection open.

**My Code So Far**

```
public void LiveStream()
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.somewhere.com");

    [...]

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        String json = reader.ReadToEnd();
        [...]
    }
    [...]
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530572/how-to-do-a-long-polling-client-in-c

Comment: Websockets (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) ? (with, for example in C#, SignarR: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr)

Answer (score 0):

You could use following snippet:

```
public async void LiveStream()
{
    using(var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(SET DESIRED TIMEOUT);
        string response = client.GetStringAsync("http://api.sample.com");
    }
}
```

or by using `HttpResponse`

```
public async void LiveStream()
{
    using(var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(SET DESIRED TIMEOUT);
        var response = client.GetAsync("http://api.sample.com");
        if(repsone.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string contentJson = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Remember: The default [TimeOut](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx) is 100 seconds.